# AngularJS: Set default select option when using directive to apply select drop down to page

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

---

EDIT/UPDATE
I have added a plunker for this issue: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mlYKJQc7zQR0dsvDswMo

---

I am loading in data from the previous page into $scope.visit in my page controller. I would like to have a directive that constructs and loads select elements on the page with options from the database. Here is what I have so far:

```
app.directive('popList', ['$http', function($http) {
    'use strict';
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            popList: '='
        },
        template: function(elem,attrs) {
            return  '<select '+
                        'ng-model="'+attrs.model+'" '+
                        'ng-options="option.name for option in ddlOpts track by option.id" '+
                        'required '+
                    '></select>';
        }
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        var data = {
                sTableName: attrs.tbl
            };
        $http.post('ddl.asmx/populateDDL',data).
        then(function(response) {
            console.log('This is the value I want to set it to '+scope.$parent.visit.data.state_id);
            //ddlOpts loads with no problem
            scope.ddlOpts = response.data.d;
        });

    }
}]);
```

Then the HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="width: 5%" class="tableLabel">State</div>
<div
    style="width: 27%;"
    class="tableInput"
    model="visit.data.state_id"
    tbl="tblStates"
    pop-list="states"
>
</div>
```

Essentially I pass in the name of the table that holds my drop down options. I also pass in the model which will tell the select what value is the default (if it has one.)

I can get the data loaded into the select element as options with no problem. I have checked the ng-model to ensure that I have the correct value to match to the ng-value. I have tried ng-repeat then started all over with ng-options but I cannot for the life of me get the select option to set the default to the ng-model value.

I am starting to think its because the when the select is constructed its in a different scope than the where the controller set the data to $scope.visit. Can someone explain why the two scopes don't recognize one another or just explain why I can't set my default value to the value stored in the ng-model?

Here is the page controller just in case you need for reference:

```
app.controller('demographicsFormCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $cookies, $http, $window, $route) {
    if (
        typeof $cookies.get('visitTrack') === 'undefined' ||
        typeof $cookies.get('visitInfo') === 'undefined' ||
        typeof $cookies.get('visitData') === 'undefined'
    ){
        window.location.href = "#/";
        return false;   
    }
    $scope.visit = {};
    $scope.visit.track = JSON.parse($cookies.get('visitTrack'));
    $scope.visit.data = JSON.parse($cookies.get('visitData'));
    $scope.visit.info = JSON.parse($cookies.get('visitInfo'));
    $rootScope.preloader = true;
    console.log('controller set');

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, thanks to [Ravi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4658387/ravi-teja) as I couldn't have found the answer without him...

OK so here is the skinny on doing this in a directive. The database was sending down an object with just a key and an integer value. Angular, when using ng-options, was creating an object with k/v pairs of id-int, name-string... As you can see here in this plunk when I converted the database data (MANUALLY) to match the outcome of the selected option it worked like a charm...

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mlYKJQc7zQR0dsvDswMo

Essentially when trying to change the value of your directive created just make sure the data object in ng-model matches the data object created by ng-options...

or if you have the same issue with the served data you can write in something after you set ddlOpts to set based on the int sent from the DB like so:

```
app.directive('popList', ['$http', function($http) {
    'use strict';
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        template: function(elem,attrs) {
            return  '<select '+
                        'ng-model="model" '+
                        'ng-options="option.name for option in ddlOpts track by option.id" '+
                        'required '+
                    '></select>';
        },
        link: link
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var defaultInt;
        if (typeof scope.model === "number"){
            defaultInt = scope.model;
        }else{
            defaultInt = parseInt(scope.model);
        }
        var data = {
                sTableName: attrs.tbl
            };
        $http.post('/emr4/ws/util.asmx/populateDDL',data).
        then(function(response) {
            scope.ddlOpts = response.data.d;
// THIS LINE BELOW HERE SETS THE VALUE POST COMPILE
            angular.forEach(scope.ddlOpts, function (v, i) {
                if (v.id === defaultInt) {
                    scope.model = v;
                }
            });
        });

    }
}]);
```

iTS ALWAYS BETTER AS A RULE OF THUMB TO HAVE YOUR DATA COMING FROM THE db MATCH WHAT ANGULAR CREATES BUT THAT IS NOT ALWAYS SO...

Answer (score 1):

```
 template: function(elem,attrs) {
            return  '<select '+
                        'ng-model="'+attrs.model+'" '+
                        'ng-options="option.name for option in ddlOpts track by option.id" '+
                        'required '+
                    '></select>';
        }
```

In the above template you have `ddlOpts`, which I believe is an array of objects. And you are displaying `name` in drop down and storing `option` in ng-model when user selects one of the name.

For `attrs.model`, you are passing data from the *main* view `model="visit.data.state_id"`. So, you are passing just an `id` to set the default option.

If you want to set an default option, you have to **pass an object matching one of the objects of `ddlOpts`**.

Also note that if you try to pass an object to `model="visit.data.state_id"`, I don't think you can read an object inside directive by `attrs.model`, since `model=""` holds a `string`.

Probably, you have add one more isolated scope binding in your directive.

```
 scope: {
            popList: '=',
            model: '='
        },
```

In HTML

```
template: function(elem,attrs) {
            return  '<select '+
                        'ng-model="'+model+'" '+
                        'ng-options="option.name for option in ddlOpts track by option.id" '+
                        'required '+
                    '></select>';
        }
```

Comment: It will not allow me to pass the isolated scope into the template. I can pass it into the link function but not the template itself. How would I go about setting it from the link function?

Comment: In your example above where you put : 'ng-model="'+model+'" '+ >>> model is not defined

Comment: Are you able to access model in link function using `scope.model`?

Comment: Yes, . I can pass it into the link function but not the template.

Comment: Try doing {{model}} in template so that you will know whether you object is accessible from the template

Comment: Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{model}}] starting at [{model}}].

Comment: Can you update question with these new code changes in directive, template and main view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125522/discussion-between-erik-grosskurth-and-ravi-teja).